# iPhone hardware Mute button muting calls on multiple devices

Tags: iphone, xamarin.forms, sip, callkit, mute

I have a iOS application with SIP calling functionality integrated into CallIKit.  Calls at the SIP server (Brekeke) are configured such that when a call is placed, it it sent to multiple phones/SIP devices.  If the hardware mute button is pressed on one of the iPhones when the call is ringing, the ringer on all of the iPhones goes silent, not just the device where the button was pressed.  I am NOT handling mute functionality in either the SIP or CallKit libraries.  This is a Xamarin.Forms app, but I don't think that that makes any difference.

Is there a way with SIP (CounterPath library) or CallKit to address this, so that the only the device where the mute button was pressed has the ringer silenced?

Comment: I can't see how this is anything other than a bug in the library you're using.  Does your code do anything in response to the mute button?  If so, post that code

Comment: No.  My code is not handling mute at all.

Comment: I suggest you open a bug with the SIP vendor

Comment: I did open a ticket with the vendor.

Comment: The issue appears to happen when multiple phones are using the same Apple ID.